# Actual Cash Value (ACV) of a remodeled mobile home

Tags: insurance, home-insurance

I have an investment mobile home manufactured in 1972. Last month a contractor was removing trees and landed a big one on my mobile home, cutting it in half and totaling it.

My question is regarding the calculation the contractor's insurance company is using which is: "ACV"

I understand this is the depreciated value. However, for a home which has been fully remodeled (I put $8k into it 3 months prior), how should the ACV be calculated? Would my repairs be depreciated as well and at what rate / how?

Comment: Good question - interested to see if any answers pop up.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably going by appraised value. If so (ask them), you could probably pay for and submit a new appraisal.

Note that your renovation has probably increased the value by considerably less than you spent on it; that's just the way renovation works.